# Is it safe to use Django south for handling migration on big project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south, django-migrations

From long time i am having migration issues. Each time i am droping my postgres database and creating a new When i add new 3/4 table or a relation or Circular migration happens. Or most of the time some unwanted issue comes in migration. 
But it's okay as long i am in development phase. But very soon when it will be on production i can't do that. Removing database each time.

I have heard a lot about django-south. But the issue is it's not updated from long time i think last time it was updated December,14(according to it's bitbucket repo).

Now is it a good choice for a project of 2018 ? Or any other 3rd party i can use. I just don't want to take rick writing raw sql each time in production as i am not too good on it as well. So i want to depend on django 100% in migration. 
Please share you ideas on the migration issue
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: South only works with Django 1.6 or less. And if you're using such an old version of Django, then it's not South you need to worry about. Your whole project is not safe/secure.

Comment: @xyres tnx your suggestion. That's i see not update after 2014 on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

South was the predecessor of `django migrate`. It became a part of Django core, so no need to install it.

If you are having migration issues, you should learn how to *fix* them, instead of just re-installing. You can edit every single migration file. They are just regular `.py` files with regular Django functions that do the necessary changes to your tables.

Read the error message, try to understand what went wrong, and fix the migration file that caused the error. They are numbered and located in `projectfolder/appfolder/migrations/`.

I am using `migrate` all the time and never had an issue that wasn't fixable.

Comment: actually main issue raise when i have lot's of foreign field. So the relation creates problem. Sometime one app require another and may be django doesn't detect any particular model for some unusual reason. Would you suggest any complete discussion on it ? I have seen official discussion but it think it would be better i get something that shows the error first and then the solution. Unlike django project doc that that just say makemigration and it's work. Tnx again for you answer